# Javascript pass value of time difference in hours * minutes * seconds * 1000

Tags: javascript

I have this JS script:

```
if ($('.count-down').length !== 0){
    $('.count-down').countdown({
        timestamp : (new Date()).getTime() + 24*60*60*1000
    });
}
```

It provides +24 hours as 24*60*60*1000 so script starts count down from 24:00:00

I need to give this script my event date as valuable format Y.m.d H:i I.E. 2014.12.31 12:00, that it would calculate the time difference between now and add it to the code.

```
var difference = getTimeDifferenceFromNow('2014.12.31 12:00')
timestamp : (new Date()).getTime() + difference
```

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Substract two `Date` instances, you will get the length between in millisecond.

```
function getTimeDifferenceFromNow(timeString) {
  return new Date(timeString) - new Date();
}

getTimeDifferenceFromNow('2014.12.31 12:00') // 818501769, roughly 9 days and half in the future.
```

**How could this work?** When you substract two `Date` instances, their `valueOf()` method is called internally, which will convert them to timestamp. Then you are actually subsctracting two timestamps, finally get a number of millisecond.

---

**EDIT**

However, I was wondering why you did in that way? If you want the timestamp of a given date/time, why don't you just instantiate it and grab its timestamp?

```
new Date('2014.12.31 12:00').getTime() // 1419998400000
```

Comment: Im trying this, but wont work, whats wrong in this code:

var eventdate  = new Date('2014.12.31 12:00').getTime();
 if ($('.count-down').length !== 0){
  $('.count-down').countdown({
   timestamp : eventdate
  });
 }

Comment: @RokasPaškevičius So what is countdown doing? Could you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

This was the final solution:

```
    var eventdate  = new Date("January 1, 2015 1:00:00").getTime();
if ($('.count-down').length !== 0){
    $('.count-down').countdown({
            timestamp :  eventdate
    });
}
```